# Visual Studio Package Initialize method does not call when debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, mef

Currently, I'm developing an extension to Visual Studio 2010 using MEF and I need to initialize my global state. I'm trying to do it in Package.Initialize method

```cs
[PackageRegistration(UseManagedResourcesOnly = true)]
[InstalledProductRegistration("#110", "#112", "1.0.0.0", IconResourceID = 400)]
[Guid("1AF4B41B-F2DF-4F49-965A-816A103ADFEF")]
public sealed class MyPackage : Package
{

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        ContainerConfigurator.Configure();
        ContainerConfigurator.IsInitialized = true;
        base.Initialize();
    }
}
```

Also I have a MEF classifier provider that uses this state

```cs
[Export(typeof(IClassifierProvider))]
[Name("This is my provider")]
[ContentType("DebugOutput")]
[ContentType("Output")]
public class MyClassifierProvider : IClassifierProvider
{
    [Import]
    private IClassificationTypeRegistryService _classificationRegistry = null; // MEF

    public IClassifier GetClassifier(ITextBuffer textBuffer)
    {
        // This always false
        if (!ContainerConfigurator.IsInitialized)
           throw new InvalidOperationException();

        return textBuffer.Properties.GetOrCreateSingletonProperty(() => new TypedClassifier(ServiceLocator.Current, _classificationRegistry));
    }
}
```

Both of package and MEF classifier are in the same assembly. When I start debugging and place a breakpoint I see that this assemly is loaded. But MyClassifierProvider has been initialized before MyPackage.Initialize call. So I can't initialize my global state before any of MEF components is started. Can anyone explain why and how can I avoid that behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I've found the answer. It is necessary to add ProvideAutoLoad attribute

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.vsconstants(v=vs.80).aspx

http://dotneteers.net/blogs/divedeeper/archive/2008/03/23/LVNSideBar1.aspx

so the final class declaration is

```
[PackageRegistration(UseManagedResourcesOnly = true)]
[InstalledProductRegistration("#110", "#112", "1.0.0.0", IconResourceID = 400)]
[Guid("1AF4B41B-F2DF-4F49-965A-816A103ADFEF")]
[ProvideAutoLoad("ADFC4E64-0397-11D1-9F4E-00A0C911004F")]
public sealed class MyPackage : Package
```

Comment: The first link is wrong, it links to VSConstants, the ProvideAutoLoad help is found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ProvideAutoLoadAttribute.aspx

Comment: `ProvideAutoLoad` attribute still valid (at least for VS 2015)